# For a round-robin tournament, what is the favorite's least favorite size?

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics

Suppose we have a round-robin tournament (i.e., each player plays exactly one game with each other player) with $n$ players, who are all equally skillful except for one player, the *favorite*, whose probability of winning a game against any other player is some fixed value $p > 1/2$. Assume that all games are independent, and also that no individual game ends in a tie.  The winner of the tournament is the player who wins the most games; let us assume that if several players are tied for first place, then one of them is chosen (uniformly) at random to be the winner.  Let $\pi(p,n)$ be the probability that the favorite wins the tournament.

**Fact.** For any fixed $p>1/2$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \pi(p,n) = 1$.

Sketch of proof: The probability that a given ordinary player scores higher than the favorite goes to zero at a rate that is exponentially fast in $n$ (by, e.g., Hoeffding's inequality), but there are only $n$ competitors, so even a union bound suffices to show that the probability that *any* player scores higher than the favorite goes to zero exponentially fast.

In light of the above Fact, it may be slightly surprising that for a fixed $p$, especially for $p$ close to $1/2$, the value of $\pi(p,n)$ actually declines for a while (as $n$ increases), and I think it may even wobble around, before eventually climbing to 1.

Intuitively, what's happening for small $n$ is that the increase in the number of *competitors* is increasing the chances that one of them will do well and upset the favorite, and that this is initially a more important effect than the fact that the increase in the number of *games* is giving the favorite an opportunity to demonstrate a skill edge.

This has led me to consider the following question.

> Let $N(\epsilon)$ denote the value of $n$ that minimizes $\pi(1/2 + \epsilon, n)$. What can be said about $N(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\to0$?

Presumably, $\lim_{\epsilon\to0} N(\epsilon) = \infty$, but approximately how fast?

Comment: I am guessing that you mean $\pi(p,n)$ everywhere.  Also, do you have  values to share of $\pi(1/2 + \epsilon,n)$ for small $n$?  Gerhard "To Start Us All Off" Paseman, 2017.04.12.

Comment: By misapplying the CLT and making unwarranted independence assumptions, I got $N\simeq 1/\epsilon^2$ as a rough guess.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman : Thanks, I fixed the typo.  I did write a program to compute some numerical estimates and was going to post them with my question, but at the last minute I realized that I used a different tiebreak rule in my code from what I said above, so I'll have to rerun the numbers.  By the way, the tiebreak rule is not set in stone; if a slightly different tiebreak rule makes the analysis easier (e.g., perhaps the first-place finishers play a round-robin tournament as a tiebreak, which means the favorite is more likely to win the tiebreak), that's fine.

Comment: I can't resist mentioning that when I was composing this question, the software saw the word "favorite" in the title and warned me that my question looked subjective and would probably be closed.

Comment: Why does the tiebreak rule matter if we're looking at asymptotic behavior? For large n the probability of ties is vanishingly small.

Comment: @ArthurB : The tiebreak rule may not matter.  However, I'm interested not in large $n$, but in $n = N(\epsilon)$, and it's not immediately obvious to me that the probability of ties is vanishingly small for this value of $n$.  Another way to put it is that I'm interested in the asymptotics as $\epsilon \to 0$, not in the asymptotics as $n\to\infty$, since the latter is already covered by the Fact I mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can show that $N(\epsilon)$ is equal to $\epsilon^{-2}$ up to a log factor on each side.

The strategy I'll use is to give an upper bound for $\pi(1/2+\epsilon,n)$. Optimizing it, we obtain an upper bound for $\pi(1/2+\epsilon,N(\epsilon))$.  Then using lower bounds for $\pi(1/2+\epsilon,n)$ we can rule out certain values of $n$ as being $N(\epsilon)$.

For any $m \geq\epsilon n$, we have the upper bound $$ \pi(1/2+\epsilon,n) \leq \frac{(1+2\epsilon)^{n/2+m} (1-2\epsilon)^{n/2-m} }{n} + e^{ - 2 (m-\epsilon n)^2/n}$$

Indeed by Hoeffding's inequality the second term is an upper bound on the probability of getting greater than $m$ wins, so it suffices to prove the first term is an upper bound on the probability of winning the tournament with at most $m$ wins. However, for each possible outcome of the tournament (specifying the winner of every match) involving at most $m$ wins for a certain player, the probability of getting it when that player is the a favorite divided by the probability of getting it if that player is the same as all the others is at most $(1+2 \epsilon)^m (1-2\epsilon)^{n-m}$ (just multiply out the probability). Hence the probability of winning the tournament with at most $m$ wins as the favorite is at most $(1+2 \epsilon)^m (1-2\epsilon)^{n-m}$ times the probability of winning the tournament as an average player and at most $m$ wins, which is at most the probability of winning the tournament as an average player, which is $< 1/n$.

We can further estimate $$  (1+2\epsilon)^{n/2+m} (1-2\epsilon)^{n/2-m} = e^{ 4 \epsilon m  - \frac{(2\epsilon)^2}{2} n + O( \epsilon^3 n
) }$$

So setting $m = \epsilon n + \sqrt{n \log n /2}$, the second term is $1/n$ and the first term is $$\frac{ e^{2 \epsilon^2 n + 2 \epsilon 
\sqrt{2 n \log n}} }{n}$$ so choosing $n$ to be approximately  $\epsilon^{-2}/ \log (\epsilon^{-1})$, the exponent is $O(1)$, so $\pi(1/2+\epsilon,n)=O(1/n) = O( \log (\epsilon^{-1})/ \epsilon^{-2})$.

Thus $\pi(1/2+\epsilon,N(\epsilon)) = O( \log (\epsilon^{-1})/ \epsilon^{-2})$.

Now using the lower bound $\pi(1/2+\epsilon, n) \geq 1/n$, we obtain $N(\epsilon) \geq  C \epsilon^{-2} / \log (\epsilon^{-1})$ for some constant $C$.

To upper bound $N(\epsilon)$, we use a different lower bound. By Hoeffding's inequality, the probability that either some player scores above $(1/2 + \epsilon/2 n)$ or the favorite scores below $(1/2 + \epsilon/2 n)$ is at most $e^{ - \epsilon^2 n /2}$, so $\pi(1/2+\epsilon,n) \geq 1 -n e^{-\epsilon^2 n/2}$. In particular, because $\pi(1/2+\epsilon,N(\epsilon))=o(1)$ then $ \epsilon^2 N(\epsilon)/2 \geq \log N(\epsilon) - o(1)$, so $N(\epsilon)/\log N(\epsilon) \geq 2 \epsilon^{-2} (1-o(1))$ and hence $N(\epsilon) \geq 4 \epsilon^{-2} \log (\epsilon^{-1}) (1+o(1))$.

Comment: "the true exponent might be true" Could you please fix this?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, I think you'd be hard-pressed to argue that the true exponent is not, in fact, true.

Comment: Yes, but you are being pressed to provide meaning, as well as truth.  Gerhard "Does Mean Well, Truthfully Speaking" Paseman, 2017.04.18.

Answer (score 1):

(**This is not a solution**. I post as an answer beacuse I don't have a privilege to leave a comment) Another approach is to begin with an elementary method that Illustrates the hardness of the problem.

I will ease the condition to a condition that no player won more games than the best player.

In that setting the native elementary approach is much easier: Let $ k = {n+1 \choose 2} $ and $ m $ be the number of the best player's wins, denote also the number of solutions for $ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = l $ by $ s(n,l) $ (trivial), and the number of solutions for $ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = l $ s.t. $ \forall i (x_i \leq b) $ by $ sb(n,l,b) $ (simple calculation using the Inclusion–exclusion principle).

Than we get that:
$$ \pi_2(p_\epsilon, n+1) = \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{sb(n,k-m,m)}{s(n,k-m)} (1/2)^{k-m} p_\epsilon^m (1-p_\epsilon)^{n-m}$$
Which is hard to analyse, so asymptotic methods like in the Arthur's answer are better.

Comment: I'm O.K. with your tiebreak rule (which can be phrased as, "the favorite always loses a tiebreak"), but I don't see how this makes the question I asked "much easier."  Can you even prove from your formula that $\lim_{\epsilon\to0} N(\epsilon) = \infty$?

Comment: I didn't expressed myself well: the combinatorial argument that gives this formula is simple, but the analysis is hard.

Comment: I also changed the tiebreak to "the favorite always wins a tiebreak".

Answer (score 1):

An Introduction:

> We have one favorite and $m\in\mathbb N:=\{1\ 2\ \ldots\}$ patzers like me for a total of $n:=m+1$ fearless chess players (who are like basketball teams--no draws are allowed). A probability win in a game between patzers is $\frac 12, $ and $\ p:=\frac 12+\epsilon\ $ for the favorite, and $\ \frac 12-\epsilon\ $ against the favorite, where $\ 0<\epsilon<\frac 12$.

Let's concentrate on the **sub**tournament of patzers only. The expected value of each of them is then$\ \frac {m-1}2.\ $ The variance of a $1$-game event between them is

$$\frac 12\cdot\left(\frac 12\right)^2
    +  \frac 12\cdot\left(\frac 12\right)^2\ =\ \frac 14 $$

Thus a variance of the whole subtournament for one player is
$\ \frac {m-1}4\ $ hence the respective standard deviation is
$\ \frac {\sqrt{m-1}}2.\ $ Thus, the probability of a patzer scoring at least $\ M\ :=\ \frac{m-1}2 + \frac{\sqrt{m-1}}2\ $ points is at least $15\% = 0.15\ $ -- a player like this would score $M$ points in $15$ tournaments out of a $100$, on average.

On the other hand, the favorite scores at the most $\ F\ :=\ m\cdot p\ $ on at least half occasions (i.e. tournaments). The games of the favorite are independent of the games between lesser competitors. Thus the probability of a patzer getting score $\ \ge M,\ $ and of favorite getting not more than $\ F,\ $ is at least $\ 7.5\%.$

However, $\ F\le M\ $ whenever

$$ p\ \le\ \frac{m-1+\sqrt{m-1}}{2\cdot m}
\,\ =\,\ \frac 12 + \frac{\sqrt{m-1}-1}{2\cdot m} $$

Then the probability of the favorite winning a tournament is not more than $\ 92.5\%:\ $

$$ \pi\ \left(\frac 12 + \frac{\sqrt{n-2}-1}{2\cdot (n-1)},\ n\right)\,\ \le\,\ 0.925 $$

This may serve as a first, very crude insight into the problem.